# Ciclos en JavaScript repite los datos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, bucles

tengo este servicio que cree con Django para consumirlo en javascript

```
[
 {
  id: 2,
  titulo: "mi segundo post",
  fecha_creacion: "2019-06-14T05:50:54.067Z",
  foto: "/media/images/uploads/post/escocia.jpg",
  categorias: [
       {
         pk: 3,
         nombre: "Rios",
         fecha_creacion: "2019-06-14T03:57:39.967Z"
       },
       {
         pk: 2,
         nombre: "Viajes largos",
         fecha_creacion: "2019-06-14T03:57:29.367Z"
       }
  ]
 },
 {
  id: 1,
  titulo: "Mi primer Post",
  fecha_creacion: "2019-06-14T03:51:16.222Z",
  foto: "/media/images/uploads/post/pragaprincipal.jpg",
  categorias: [
       {
         pk: 1,
         nombre: "Viajes cortos",
         fecha_creacion: "2019-06-14T03:49:47.186Z"
       }
  ]
 }
]
```

```
function getLastPost(){
    $.get("api-posts/get-last-post",function(json) {
        var lastPost = ""
        for (let i in json) {
            for (let j in json[i].categorias) {
                lastPost += 
                '<div class="latest-post" href="#">'+
                    '<div class="l-post-image"><img src="'+json[i].foto+'" alt="Category Image"></div>'+
                    '<div class="post-info">'+
                        '<a class="btn category-btn" href="#">'+json[i].categorias[j].nombre+'</a>'+
                        '<h5><a href="#"><b class="light-color">'+json[i].titulo+'</b></a></h5>'+
                        '<h6 class="date"><em>'+json[i].fecha_creacion+'</em></h6>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'
                }
            }
        $("#lastPost").html(lastPost);
    });
}

getLastPost()
```

Cuando voy a mostrarlo en un html que cree, por cada categoría que ingrese me repite el post, es decir, en el primer post tengo dos categorías(ríos y viajes largos) entonces el mismo post se repite dos veces, y así si tuviera 3 y cuatro se repiten cuantas categorías tenga, se que ese ciclo no esta bien porque ya hice pruebas de escritorio y pues me da lo que muestra, quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que me muestre las categorías a un solo post

si hay duda me lo muestra así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu codigo funciona bien.

Comment: No funciona bien porque no quiero repetir "mi segundo post" cada vez que agregue una cateogoria, ahi se repiten dos veces porque tengo dos categorias para ese post pero si tuviera 6 categorias para ese post, el post se repite 6 veces y no es la lidea

Comment: Como ya te respondieron, lo que no quieres que se repita, sacalo del segundo `for`

Answer (score 1):

Pienso que el código HTML que utilizas para crear la parte del post es la sección que tiene una foto. Inserta ese código fuera del segundo for pero dentro del primero:

```
for (let i in json) {
                lastPost += 
                '<div class="latest-post" href="#">'+
                    '<div class="l-post-image"><img src="'+json[i].foto+'" alt="Category Image"></div>'+
                    '<div class="post-info">';
            for (let j in json[i].categorias) {
                lastPost +=
                        '<a class="btn category-btn" href="#">'+json[i].categorias[j].nombre+'</a>'+
                        '<h5><a href="#"><b class="light-color">'+json[i].titulo+'</b></a></h5>'+
                        '<h6 class="date"><em>'+json[i].fecha_creacion+'</em></h6>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'
                }
            }
```